# Put labels on points on the y-axis and on points on a column parallel to the y-axis

Tags: plotting

I want to put (to the left of the point) j = 1 to the point (0,0), j = 2 to the point (0,1/149), j = 3 to the point (0,2/149) and j = N to the point (0,3/149).

Also put (to the right of the point) j = 1 to the point (1,0), j = 2 to the point (1,1/149), j = 3 to the point (1,2/149) and j = N to the point (1,3/149).

Also put the three points "..." vertically instead of horizontally.

It doesn't matter if it's not framed.

I tried it as follows:

```
data = Transpose@Table[{i - 1, (j - 1)/149}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 4}];
c1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black,PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 7}, AspectRatio -> 1];
c2 = ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}}, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1];
c = Show[c1, c2, Ticks -> None, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "j=1"}, {1/149, "j=2"}, {2/149, 
   "j=3"}, {(2/149) + (1/298), "..."}, {3/149, "j=N"}}, 
 Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of options `FrameStyle`, `FrameTicksStyle` and custom ticks:

```
data = Transpose @ Table[{i - 1, (j - 1)/149}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 4}];
labels = Style[#, 16] & /@ {"j = 0", "j = 1",  "  ⋮  ", "j = N"};
ticks = Thread[{(Range[4] - 1)/149, labels, 0}];

ListPlot[data, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Medium]],
  PlotStyle -> Black,
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, ticks}, {Automatic, None}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Opacity[1], Opacity[1]}, { Automatic,  Opacity[0]}},
  FrameStyle -> {{Opacity[0], Opacity[0]}, { Automatic,  Opacity[0]}}, 
  Epilog -> {Thick, Black, Line[{{{0, 0}, {0, 3/149}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 3/149}}}]},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap the input data with `Labeled`:

```
sides =  {Left, Right};
dt = Table[Labeled[{i - 1, (j - 1)/149}, labels[[j]], sides[[i]]], {i, 1,  2}, {j, 4}];

ListPlot[dt, 
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Medium]],
 ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Black, Line[{{{0, 0}, {0, 3/149}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 3/149}}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It has been helpful but I still haven't been able to get the figure. The columns are missing and the x-axis must match j = 1.

Comment: @edwards, please see the new version.

Comment: Could the frame be removed and the axes appear so that the bottom point coincides with the x-axis?

Comment: @edward, you can use the second approach with  `Frame->False` and `Axes->{True, False}`.